# How to verify the distance between 2 canadian zip code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, zipcode

I would like to know what is the best way to get the distance between 2 (zip code) or postal code in Canada. I have seen post about MySQL doing so with US zip code.

Or I guess that I could probably translate a zip code to coordinates and then triangulate distances? If anyone can share tips on this I would apreciate!

Im working with Angular JS and Node JS but I could do with PHP as well.

An Api should be free and be able to handle large ammount of querys.

Thank You

Comment: I would imagine it could be done with the Google Maps API.  But how much is a "large amount of queries"?

Comment: Take a look at the [google-distance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance) API, its a node package and looks like it will do what you need.

Comment: "An Api should be free and be able to handle large ammount of querys". Not asking for much are you. As it stands this question is not really appropriate for SO. Please head on over to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about Asking.

Comment: Well each user will browse i assume up to a hundred items and each view will require me to check if the distance matchs the criteria set by the user

Comment: @gforce301 The only thing here that is not appropriate for SO imo is your comment. But thanks for trying!

Comment: @MadeInDreams From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Try reading the help center. Thanks for trying!

Comment: This "distance" is liable to be wildly inaccurate for certain regions. Some postal codes represent a staggeringly large area.

Comment: @tadman i guess you are right but this will still give me good enough data for the purpose.

Comment: Just something to be aware of, but 90% of the time it's "good enough". Hope you're not dealing with Alaska or Nunavut all that often.

Comment: @gforce301 No hard feeling. I just ended up on stack googling this and most snipet I found are out dated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API can do it, by setting `origin` and `destination` on the distancematrix API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=M4C4Y7&destinations=H1A0A2

Comment: Make sure you understand google's terms of service for using this distance matrix results. They get a little "grumpy" if you don't follow the rules.